# Asking about infinitive and gerund

Tags: writing

Recently I was doing exercises from my textbook. There was a question that asked me to write a letter. I was thinking about the beginning of the letter, but I can't determine which sentence was correct or the best. Here are three sentences I thought:
1. It's been a long time since I wrote to you.
2. It's been a long time not to write to you.
3. It's been a long time not writing to you.

If all of them are incorrect, please help give me a correct one. And the main question is I don't know the difference between 2 and 3, that is 'to write' and 'writing', as I know they can interchange in most cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sentence is correct.

Sentences 2 and 3 are incorrect, because you haven't identified **who** is writing the letter(there is no subject in them) and also they need one conjunction.

Note that you are joining 2 sentences (**It's been a long time** and **I wrote to you**) so you should use one conjunction.